# Updating Mcafee Group Shield on Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-2007, anti-virus, mcafee

So I don't actually have a problem yet, but I might.

You see my fathers company have 10 computers and an exchange server with Mcafee Group Shield.
lately they've had issues with mails from customers being blocked.

I found both the problem and the solution:

[Mcafee update](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB53009)

so basicly update their Mcafee group shield to the newest service pack and we are all back in buisness.. while I have some limited exchange experience and AD too.
I don't have any Mcafee experience.

I don't wanna crash their server for a week and have them need to get someone to recover it.
So my question in here.. is it supposedly as easy as to click an 'update' button and to reboot your server.. or are there several issues I need to be aware about..?

Maybe there is some common issue that goes with updating antivirus on an exchange server that I don't know about..

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late for you as you asked a good while ago.

But McAfee Groupshield (and other Exchange A/V products) talk to Exchange using something called VSAPI; this is provided by Exchange itself (*Virus Scan API*)

So if Groupshield goes wrong, simply kill it all off and stop the service and Exchange will carry on working (obviously sans virus / spam protection)

This gives you some time to sort the issue out properly, without affecting production service.